# React - How to notify child component which uses a props-rest-call-function that REST-call has resolved?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I submit an object/issue I am calling a function of the parent component, which has been passed to the child component as props.
After sending my data I want to clear my input fields. The Problem is, that I am clearing my input fields immediately after calling addNewIssue(). I actually want to wait until the POST-Call has resolved.

If I only had one component I could just clear the input fields after e.g. setissueList(newIssueList), since state and rest-call would be in the same component.

**How can I notify the child component that the POST-Call has resolved and only then it should clear the inputs?**

I tried to google this problem, but I couldn't find anything. Most likely I am not using the right words. I assume it has to do something with promises and the solution might be simple but I am not an expert regarding promises or async.

```
// parent component
const addNewIssue = (issue) => {
  axios.post(url + '/forms/issue', issue, headers).then((res) => {
    let newIssueList = [...issueList, res.data];
    setissueList(newIssueList);
  });
}

<NewIssue addNewIssue={addNewIssue} />


// child component
const const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  addNewIssue(inputs);
  setInputs({
    summary: "",
    description: ""
   });
 }
```

Comment: simply update the props you are passing down. Updating children is basically for free, since thats the natural direction of state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your API request along with a callback

```
// parent component
const addNewIssue = (issue,cb) => {
  axios.post(url + '/forms/issue', issue, headers).then((res) => {
    let newIssueList = [...issueList, res.data];
    setissueList(newIssueList);
    cb()
  });
}

<NewIssue addNewIssue={addNewIssue} />


// child component
const const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
const cb=()=>{setInputs({
    summary: "",
    description: ""
   });}
  addNewIssue(inputs,cb);
  
 }
```

Comment: That was a really simple solution. Thanks!